Azure SQL Failover Group fails on second run
I've setup an AzureSQL failover group using a bicep, with very simple settings. The first deployment works as expected. If I deploy again, without making any changes, I get this error:
The property targetServer of the read-only endpoint must be a valid server present among the partnerServers configured for the failover group.
The second run uses the same servers as before, and all should be valid.
I'm not sure what this is telling me?
Here is my bicep:
param failoverGroupName string
param primarySqlServerName string
param secondarySqlServerName string
param databaseName string
param secondaryResourceGroup string

resource primary 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-08-01-preview' existing = {
  name:  primarySqlServerName
}

resource secondary 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-08-01-preview' existing = {
  name:  secondarySqlServerName
  scope: resourceGroup(secondaryResourceGroup)
}

resource sqlServerFailoverGroup 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/failoverGroups@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  name: failoverGroupName
  parent: primary
  properties: {
    databases: [
      resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', primarySqlServerName,databaseName)
    ]
    readWriteEndpoint: {
      failoverPolicy: 'Automatic'
      failoverWithDataLossGracePeriodMinutes: 60
    }
    readOnlyEndpoint: {
      failoverPolicy: 'Enabled'
    }
    partnerServers: [
      {
        id: secondary.id
      }
    ]
  }
}



Azure SQL Failover Group fails on second run:

I tried deploying the same code as given in this SO again and was able to deploy it as expected which is shown below.

Try clearing the cache and again deploy the whole bicep code. Or restore the bicep file with the respective path using az bicep restore --file filename.bicep so that it restores the file in the current environment.
If still the issue persists, add target server (secondary server) property under readOnlyEndpoint as shown below to avoid your error.
resource sqlServerFailoverGroup 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/failoverGroups@2023-05-01-preview' = {
   name: failoverGroupName
   parent: primary
   properties: {
     databases: [
      resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', primarySqlServerName,databaseName)
     ]
     readWriteEndpoint: {
       failoverPolicy: 'Automatic'
      failoverWithDataLossGracePeriodMinutes: 60
     }
     readOnlyEndpoint: {
       failoverPolicy: 'Enabled'
       targetServer: secondary.id
    }
     partnerServers: [
      {
        id: secondary.id
      }
     ]
   }
 }

Deployment succeeded:


I add the targetServer property that you suggested, but I am still getting the error.  You mentioned that you were 'able to deploy it as expected'. Did you deploy twice?  For me, it works fine on the intial deployment and I get the error on the next deployment.

Yes I have deployed twice and it worked as expected. @DonChambers
